# How do I pass an email address to Auth.federatedSignIn using AWS amplify

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml, aws-amplify

I have users from many organisations, each of which has their own SAML IDP. I'm using AWS Cognito and Amplify to try to make a sane login workflow where a user is redirected to their organisation's IDP when they try to log in.

My desired workflow is

1. the user types in their email address,
2. based on that email address, the system can determine which organisation the user is from
3. call Auth.federatedSignIn with custom parameters that point to the IDP configured in Cognito

The stumbling block is that I can't work out how to tell Auth.federatedSignIn what the user's email address was, so they end up having to type it in again at their IDP's login page.

Has anyone got any idea how this works?

Comment: What IdPs allow username (implemented as email address or whatever) to be prefilled?

Comment: It's a good question - I don't know which, I've not tried to do it before.

Comment: None of the major IdPs allow prefill to prevent [phishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434415/how-can-i-pre-fill-email-for-saml-google-idp/55485279#55485279) attacks

Comment: That's super useful information. Thanks. If you want to make that an answer, I'll gladly give you a tick.